# React-native UI Component, MediaPlayer not called after when resume from task/menu button

Tags: android, react-native

i wanna create android component, and in this component i have video player, that using MediaPlayer with SurfaceTexture. When i try that compoent in sample app, it work fine. But when i tried to press Home Button (Circle Button in android Device) then open again the app from history off running app (press button task/menu then click the apps), the Media Player Not Called normally. But if i click app icon again media player work normally. anyone know what happen ?

I try to logging when i resume it from background app, and it say

```
04-09 17:42:13.160 330-22013/? E/MediaPlayerService: setVideoSurfaceTexture failed: -19
04-09 17:44:49.944 453-453/com.videofiltertest E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 0
04-09 17:44:49.945 453-453/com.videofiltertest E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

thanks.

**This my native component code.**

```
public class VideoPlayer extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, LifecycleEventListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

private static final String TAG = VideoThumbnail.class.getSimpleName();
public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
public VideoTextureRenderer mRenderer;
private int surfaceWidth;
private int surfaceHeight;
private ThemedReactContext mContext;
private String videoPath;
private String fragmentShaderCode = null;

private boolean isCrop = false;
private boolean isAutoPlay = false;
private boolean isLooping = false;
private boolean mediaPlayerReady = false;
private boolean isTextureAvailable = false;

private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
private SurfaceTexture surface = null;
private int xpos;

private int seekto = 0;

private boolean isPaused = false;
private boolean isCreated = false;
private boolean mediaPlayerPrepared = false;


public VideoPlayer(ThemedReactContext context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
    this.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}

public VideoPlayer(ThemedReactContext context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
    this.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    surfaceHeight = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    surfaceWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(surfaceWidth, surfaceWidth);
}

private void getSurface(){
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (surface != null) {
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    isCreated = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("DEBUG", e.toString());
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not open input video!");
                }
            } else {
                surface =  mRenderer.getVideoTexture();
                getSurface();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

private void setup(){

    if(mMediaPlayer == null){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }
    if(mRenderer == null){
        mRenderer = new VideoTextureRenderer(mContext, surfaceTexture, surfaceWidth, surfaceWidth );
    }

    getSurface();
}

public void setSource(String src){
    videoPath = src;
}

public void setFilter(int filterCode){
    switch (filterCode){
        ...
    }

    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mRenderer.setShader(fragmentShaderCode);
    }
}

public void setCrop(boolean isCrop){
    this.isCrop = isCrop;
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
        mRenderer.setCrop(this.isCrop);
    }
}

public void togglePlayPause(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }else{
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isPlaying(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }
    return false;
}

public void setPaused(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}

public void setStop(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

public void setStart(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}

public void seekTo(int time){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(time);
    }else{
        seekto = time;
    }
}

public boolean isPlayerReady(){
    return mediaPlayerReady;
}

public int getCurrentPos(){
    if(mediaPlayerReady){
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getDuration(){
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public void setAutoPlay(boolean isAutoPlay){
    this.isAutoPlay = isAutoPlay;
}

public void setLooping(boolean isLooping){
    this.isLooping = isLooping;
}

@Override
public void onHostResume() {
    if(isPaused){
        resume();
        isPaused = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onHostPause() {
    pause();
}

@Override
public void onHostDestroy() {
    cleanup();
}

public void resume(){
    Log.e("DEBUG","IN RESUME");
}

public void pause(){
    Log.e("DEBUG","IN PAUSE ");
    if (mMediaPlayer != null){
        Log.e("DEBUG","!NULL MPLAYER");
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    if (mRenderer != null){
        Log.e("DEBUG","!NULL MRENDER");
        mRenderer.onPause();
        mRenderer = null;
    }

    surfaceTexture = null;
    mediaPlayerReady = false;
    isPaused = true;
}

public void cleanup() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "CLEAN ");
    if(mMediaPlayer != null){
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
    if(mRenderer != null){
        mRenderer.onPause();
    }
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "surface avalilable");
    isTextureAvailable = true;
    surfaceTexture = surface;
    surfaceWidth = width;
    surfaceHeight = height;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "MASUK ONPREPARED");

    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surface));
            mRenderer.setDimension(mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight());
            mRenderer.setShader(fragmentShaderCode);
            mRenderer.setCrop(isCrop);

            if(!mMediaPlayer.isLooping()){
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
            }

            if(isAutoPlay){
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }else{
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(seekto);
            }

            mediaPlayerReady = true;
        }
    });
    thread.run();        
}
}
```

**This the UI Manager code**

```
public class RNVideoPlayerManager extends SimpleViewManager<VideoPlayer>{
private static final String REACT_CLASS = "RNVideoEditPlayer";

private static final String PROPS_SRC = "src";
private static final String PROPS_CROP = "isCrop";
private static final String PROPS_SEEK = "seekTo";
private static final String PROPS_AUTOPLAY = "isAutoPlay";
private static final String PROPS_LOOPING = "isLoop";
private static final String PROPS_FILTER = "filter";

@Override
public String getName(){
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
public VideoPlayer createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext themedReactContext){
    return new VideoPlayer(themedReactContext);
}

@Override
public void onDropViewInstance(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
    super.onDropViewInstance(videoPlayer);
    videoPlayer.cleanup();
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_SRC)
public void setSource(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final String src){
    videoPlayer.setSource(src);
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_CROP, defaultBoolean = false)
public void setCrop(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final boolean isCrop){
    videoPlayer.setCrop(isCrop);
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_SEEK, defaultInt = -1)
public void seekTo(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final int seekTime){
    if(seekTime > 0){
        videoPlayer.seekTo(seekTime);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_AUTOPLAY, defaultBoolean = false)
public void setAutoPlay(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final boolean isAutoPlay){
    videoPlayer.setAutoPlay(isAutoPlay);
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_LOOPING, defaultBoolean = false)
public void setLoop(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final boolean isLoop){
    videoPlayer.setLooping(isLoop);
}

@ReactProp(name = PROPS_FILTER, defaultInt = 0)
public void setFilter(final VideoPlayer videoPlayer, final int filterId){
    videoPlayer.setFilter(filterId);
}
}
```

**And this my javascript component code**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {
AppRegistry,
requireNativeComponent,
View
} from 'react-native'
var iface = {
name: 'VideoPlayer',
propTypes: {
    src : PropTypes.string,
    isCrop : PropTypes.bool,
    seekTo : PropTypes.number,
    isAutoPlay : PropTypes.bool,
    isLoop : PropTypes.bool,
    filter : PropTypes.number,
    ...View.propTypes,
}
}
const VideoPlayer = requireNativeComponent('RNVideoEditPlayer', iface)
export class VideoEditPlayer extends Component{
static propTypes = {
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isCrop : PropTypes.bool,
    seekTo : PropTypes.number,
    isAutoPlay : PropTypes.bool,
    isLoop : PropTypes.bool,
    filter : PropTypes.number,
    style : PropTypes.object,
    ...View.propTypes, 
}
static defaultProps = {
    filter : 0,
    isCrop : false,
    isLoop : false,
    isAutoPlay : false,
}

constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render(){
    const{
        src,
        isCrop,
        isLoop,
        isAutoPlay,
        seekTo,
        filter,
        style,
        ...props
    } = this.props
    return(
        <VideoPlayer
            style={style}
            src={src}
            isCrop={isCrop}
            isAutoPlay={isAutoPlay}
            isLoop={isLoop}
            filter={filter}
            seekTo={seekTo}
            {...props}
        />
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @alroc is that enough ?

Comment: Is that the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the issue? Or a dump of all your code?

Comment: @alroc the step of my problem is :
1. i open my sample app that using my compoent (component code up there), the app show the video normally. Then;
2. i press home button (the midle button in android device). Then;
3. i open background app then choose my sample app. The app opened, but not show any of video. And i got error message up there.

But if i use this step :
1. i open my sample app that using my compoent (component code up there), the app show the video. Then;
2. i press home button (the midle button in android device). Then;
3. i press sample app icon again, it work normally.